# Маршрутизация с ограничениями параметров маршрутов в asp.net core 2.2. razor pages C#

Tags: c#, маршрутизация, razor, asp.net-core-2, page

Необходимо реализовать функционал страницы, чтобы в зависимости от URL запроса отображались нужные данные, а именно:
в запросе меняется последняя секция "/a": http://localhost:52747/Products/a
(a,b,c,d...и так далее)
Для заранее определенных запросов (прописанных на странице) я нашел решение с использованием директивы `@page "{name:regex(^(a|b|c|d)$)}"` и регулярного выражения.

Проблема заключается в том, что в данной конструкции данные должны быть определены из текстового файла или из коллекции IList.

Схема с переменной не работает: `@page "{name:regex(^(" + s + ")$)}"`
@page "{name:alpha}" тоже не вариант.
Пытался найти решение с маршрутизацией в Startup.cs, но ничего не вышло.

Было бы идеальным решение, которое можно реализовать в PageModel (.cshtml.cs - файл)  самой страницы.

Если у кого-то был опыт затрагивающий данную проблему, прошу поделиться решением.
Спасибо.

Содержание файла Index.cshtml

```html
@page "{name:regex(^(a|b|c|d)$)}"

@model Routing.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "IndexProducts";
}

<h1>IndexProducts</h1>

<h2>Name = @Model.Name</h2>
```

Содержание файла Index.cshtml.cs

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Routing
{
    
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Оставьте параметр name просто string'ой и первое что делаете в OnGet - проверяйте строку так как вам вздумается, в случае ошибки выкидывайте нужный вам экран, а иначе показывайте то. что собирались.

Comment: Необходимо иметь возможность определять строку параметров ограничения маршрута из кода: string s = "a|b|c|d";
[Route("name:regex(^(" + s + ")$)")] - Но не знаю с какой стороны к этому подступиться. Предложение @A K♦ в полной мере обеспечивает нужный функционал. Но все-таки, имеется возможность управлять параметрами маршрутизации из кода .cs файла?

Comment: Я бы ответил что такой возможности нет, но вся штука в том, что подобного рода вопросы сложно ручаться: толи действительно нет, толи ты просто не ковырял движок так глубоко и не все закоулки документации обшарил. Поэтому осторожно скажу лишь, что сам я такого не видел.